# Nexus 10 - Android 5.0.1 OTA upgrade, "no command" and suggested steps failed

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, ota-update, samsung-nexus-10

I was trying to install the OTA upgrade on my Nexus 10 running Lollipop 5.0.1. Got the "no command" problem. I tried the steps below from [this link](https://support.google.com/nexus/forum/AAAANseOu18WF6iOz7-XQY).

> I suggest you try the following:
>
> Press and hold Power button until your device powers off (it could take 30 seconds).
>
> 1. Press and hold Power and Volume Down buttons simultaneously until you see something other than Google on the screen.
> 2. You should see a large arrow at the top of the screen.
> 3. Tap Volume Down repeatedly until you see Recovery in the arrow. Then tap the Power button
> 4. You should see an android on his back, chest open with a red triangle and exclamation mark.
> 5. While holding Power button tap Volume Up once then release Power.
> 6. You should now see a list of items at top of screen.
> 7. Tap Power Down until the item to erase or wipe the cache partition is highlighted. Then tap Power button to initiate.
> 8. Status messages will appear at ths bottom of the screen. Be patient - it can take 10-15 minutes to complete. When done restart the Nexus.
>
> Wiping the cache partition does not impact any of your data, but it may take a while before your apps repopulate their cache values. During this time some may appear a bit slower than previously.

- I can't get past step 1, as when I do that, it keeps saying, "download in progress. do not close target ( or similar)".
- I tried the Power + Volume up + Volume down buttons, and get the menu, but don't see as below.
- I also tried Nexus Root Toolkit flash + restock, and that also shows "finished", but reboot goes back to "no command".

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  Called google support.  Had to press Power + volume UP to get to second level menu, then select clear cache option.  Re-booted and 5.0.1 upgrade continued.

Answer (score 0):

Was using Nexus 10 and stuck at "No command.." message. Had to use "Power+ volume down" buttons simultaneously to Stock Recovery mode.

> Power + Volume-up = Downloading mode
>   Power + Volume-down = Recovery mode